# Checking if a folder/file is in the same folder as the executable

Tags: c#, io, installation

I have a program I'm writing which will run from an executable. Its purpose is to take a set of files and copy them into the AppData folder for the current user. The .exe will be for example, in path: `C:\Users\username\MyDocuments\programInstall\install.exe`, and the files it will install will (most likely) be in `C:\Users\username\MyDocuments\programInstall\folderToCopy`. I need to check and make sure that the files are in that folder before I try to install. Thing is, I actually have no idea what the parent folder of `install.exe` and `folderToCopy` will be. How can I find out what that is?

Comment: if they're always supposed to be in the `folderToCopy` subdir, then you shouldn't care what the parent dir is. just use `fileExists('folderToCopy/whatever.txt')`-type code to check. e.g. use relative paths.

Comment: It will automatically hook to it if it's in the same folder?